# how to use Visual Studio Code simple ftp extension but in ACTIVE MODE ,not passive

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

I am able to connect to my xamp ftp server using active mode. but when i try to use Visual Studio Code  simple password extension configuration this all I see

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sample-Name",
        "host": "Sample-Host",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "Your FTP USERNAME",
        "password": "Your FTP PASSWORD",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true
    }
]
```

I don't see an option to choose between active and passive, any one know what I could to this confirmation file so I can choose active mode, what5 can I add to  this json file? thank you

i tried adding mode line to the json file

```
[
    {
        "name": "Sample-Name",
        "host": "Sample-Host",
        "port": 21,
        "type": "ftp",
        "username": "Your FTP USERNAME",
        "password": "Your FTP PASSWORD",
        "path": "/",
        "autosave": true,
        "confirm": true,
         "mode": active

    }
]
```